# Warning level of validation using XSD Scheme

Tags: xml, maven, xsd

I have XSD Scheme for my xml files. To validate files I am using `xml-maven-plugin`, but if I have some errors, build will be dropped. And it's okey, but I want to have, for example, `WARNING` in some situations instead of `ERROR`. Is it possible to set Scheme or plugin to create `ERROR` in one option and `WARNING` in another?